# How does access control work on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, nas

I would like to have user access rules on a central Music folder. In other words, I am the owner and editor and the kids can only copy downs music but certainly not change anything (like my tags). How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using iTunes? If yes, did you look into Home Sharing already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set up option will Share your music with others on your local network.

Settings for iTunes sharing

[image]

If we are talking about standard Folers (not iTunes) but just any folder in Finder.

Right click on the folder

Select

> Get info

In that window look all the way at the bottom, there is

> small lock

[image]

Open it (with your password)

Now you can modify "others" as they show up in your list the access to this folder to

> read only

.

Comment: Thanks, this was however not exactly what I was after. Forget iTunes and Music for a moment and just pretend this question is about simple files. How can I set access control of a full folder and its subfolders such that I have all privileges and my kids can only read (and thus open and copy only)?

Comment: OK, lets talk about that. Only one question for you: how do your kids access your computer (as different users not administrators), via remote access or how?

Comment: We are talking about files on a shared network drive. So they would not access my computer. Master files are on my computer and with some little sync software I keep these the same as the network share. However, I do not want them to screw up the network share since that is also used by the music system.

Comment: The obvious way would be to manage this through accounts on the shared network drive but for some other reasons I do not want to do this. So, ideally, I would Ike to keep using one shared network drive with limited permissions for the kids.